# can i use both sort and filter at same time in grid using vaadin24 hilla?

Tags: reactjs, vaadin-grid, lit, vaadin24, hilla

I want my grid with both  and .I dont know how to do that.Now i can use only one at a time.

```
                           <Grid
                              column-reordering-allowed
                              theme="column-borders row-stripes compact wrap-cell-content" 
                            >
                                <GridSortColumn path="supplierId"   className='s_gridsort_modify' />
                                 <GridFilterColumn path="supplierName"  className='s_gridsort_modify' />
                            </Grid> in this case only works sorting.i want bot at same grid.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.